# Laravel custom controller method calling

Tags: php, laravel, routes

I need basic help, as I am new to Laravel.

#### Situation

I have a controller **ArticlesController** which has index method which lists all articles and it's working fine. This route below, allows me to show individual articles by 'id' like this articles/id example articles/35 . But i also need to show all articles from category "Swimming" . When I hit articles/swimming it will look for id=swimming. But I don't know how to make custom route to list all articles from "Swimming" category. I have made a method "swimming" inside controller but I need help with route?

```
  Route::bind('articles', function($value, $route) {
     return $list = App\Article::whereid($value)->first();
    
    });
```

Comment: `Route::get('articles/category/{cat}', function($value){ return $list = App\Article::where('category','=',$value')->first(); })`

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create/use two separate routes, one for `articles by id` and another for `articles by category`, so for example, routes could be declared like:

```
Route::get('articles', 'ArticleController@index');

Route::get('articles/{id}', 'ArticleController@getById')->where('id', '[0-9]+');

Route::get('articles/{category}', 'ArticleController@getByCategory')->where('category', '[A-Za-z]+');
```

Then you may use `Controller Method`s like (in `ArticleController.php`):

```
public function index()
{
    return App\Article::all();
}

public function getById($id)
{
    return App\Article::whereId($id)->first();
}

public function getByCategory($category)
{
    return App\Article::with(['category' => function($q) use($category)
    {
       $q->where('category', $category);

    }])->get();

}
```

This is just a basic idea, you can improve it, anyways.

Comment: I personally like to add a pattern if it's something that is fairly standard, like `Route::pattern("id", "[0-9]+");` Seems to keep routes a bit cleaner.

Comment: Yes, you can add a global pattern, Check the [Global Constraints](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/routing#parameters-regular-expression-constraints) section.